# Retrieve a list of browsers/agents installed in client system

Tags: java, javascript, python, django, web-applications

I would like to write a web application (in django) which scans the client/remote computers (assumption is windows) and retrieve the list of software's(mainly browsers) installed. Looking for suggestions to implement it.

- Is this possible without asking the user to download any scritps/exe's?
- If so, is it possible via java script?

I am planning to use python/django to write the entire app. Any input would be much appreciated.

EDIT : Comments on feasibility in java also much appreciated

Comment: Good luck with that. What constitutes a browser on the client? Do you include Microsoft's help viewer, which normally displays local files (but in a compiled HTML format)? Do you include wget? Do you include my program that embeds a web browser control?

Comment: Why? To force people to use the only browser you could be arsed to test that your site works with or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **No, it is not possible**

Long answer: This is something that any sane (operating) system designer / administrator would  try to prevent - scanning of local system by a web page. However, you could use a plug-in component, such as a java applet, to do so - but in practice you probably would need to handle each client platform (OS) separately, since each of them has a different way of storing the information of installed software

Answer (score 1):

You want to access the data from the client side so from the conceptual/logically its not good to access the client system. You have to use some medium which run on client side on behalf of server.

JavaScript and JavaApplet is good in this. You can get the data by JavaScript or Applet and in backend you can send data to the server.

Comment: Javascript & Applets runs in the browser's sandbox. It can't access system details. It seems to be only signed applets can do this job.

Comment: btw, do you know how to access the same via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless you have some signed control installed on the client computer; or have them download a program which runs (separate from a browser) and sends the information to your server, where your django app can access it.

This is not possible using javascript (as it runs in a sandbox).

Answer (score 0):

"Scanning" a client from a server may be possible if you break their security or get them to break it for you through some extension (see windows udate, for example). Either way, it's evil.